# How to differentiate between Integer and integer stored as a string in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Using Bigquery procedures, I need to detect the data type of a value in a column of a table. I cannot read it from schema of the table.
Sometimes, the value can be an integer or an integer stored as a string. How to differentiate between both in BigQuery.

I tried SAFE_CAST like below
`sql Select count(*) from table where SAFE_CAST(column AS STRING) is NULL`
`sql Select count(*) from table where SAFE_CAST(column AS INT64) is NULL`

And, I tried Regular expression

But, both scenarios pass these conditions. Please help

Comment: I am sure for SAFE_CAST(col as int64 ) you would be getting a count > 0. Is it? which then means that there are values which cannot be casted as INT64.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time..Consider value '123' as an example..This can be casted to Integer and it wont return Null, but this is a string not an integer..

Comment: Doesn't this answers the query you have ?

Comment: Hi..Unfortunately, No..Even Number 123 can be casted to Integer and it wont return Null..How am I differentiating between Integer(123) and string('123') here with SELF_CAST here?

Comment: whats the data type of col?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot detect it from schema/datatype of col part of my framework. I need to detect from Value in the column only

Comment: Then you should try ops such as * or / to that col to know the schema. Safe_cast wont help here